# How would I read info from one txt file into two arrays? c++

Tags: c++

This is the txt file I am working with:

```
Tables: table #, max seats
1 2
2 4 
3 2 
4 2 
5 2 
6 4 
7 6 
8 10 
9 2 
10 4 
11 4 
12 4 
13 4 
14 2 
15 2 
16 2 
17 2 
18 2

Menu: listing of the full menu: item code, name, price
A1 Bruschetta 5.29
A2 Caprese_Flatbread 6.10
A3 Artichoke-Spinach_Dip 3.99
A4 Lasagna_Fritta 4.99
A5 Mozzarella_Fonduta 5.99
E1 Lasagna_Classico 6.99
E2 Capellini_Pomodoro 7.99
E3 Eggplant_Parmigiana 8.99
E4 Fettuccine_Alfredo 7.49
E5 Tour_of_Italy 14.99
D1 Tiramisu 2.99
D2 Zeppoli 2.49
D3 Dolcini 3.49
S1 Soda 1.99
S2 Bella_Limonata 0.99
S3 Berry_Acqua_Fresca 2.88
```

I want to read the table max seats into one array and the menu information into a string array. How would I skip the first line of the text file `"Tables: table #, max seats"` while reading into my first array? How would I start reading into the second array from the middle of the file disregarding the `"Menu: listing of the full menu: item code, name, price"`?

Comment: `if (line == 0)` perhaps?

Comment: You can change it again if you like -- but it was a mess after your last attempt. Read discard 1st line with `getline`, then loop `while (f >> a >> b)` then loop reading the remainder into your 2nd array. Edit and *Add* the code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you an example and give you detailed explanation on this implementation. But first I want to give you the recommendation to split the big problem in many smaller problems. Then, first solve the smaller problems. That will be very easy. Then, we use the existing solution from the smaller problem, to solve the bigger problem. With that, even the bigger problem will become easier to solve.

That will make life easier. Please see the example solution below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

// One Table and the maximum number of seats
struct TableAndSeats {
    unsigned int tableNumber{};
    unsigned int maxSeats{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TableAndSeats& tas) {
        return is >> tas.tableNumber >> tas.maxSeats;
    }
    // Simple output with inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TableAndSeats& tas) {
        return os << "Table number " << std::setw(2) << tas.tableNumber << " has " << tas.maxSeats << " seats\n";
    }
};

// One menu entry
struct MenuEntry {

    std::string itemCode{};
    std::string name{};
    double price{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, MenuEntry& me) {
        return is >> me.itemCode >> me.name >> me.price;
    }
    // Simple output with inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MenuEntry& me) {
        return os << "# " << me.itemCode << "   " << std::left << std::setw(25) << me.name << " --> " << me.price << " $\n";
    }
};

struct Tables {
    std::vector<TableAndSeats> tables{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Tables& t) {
        // Search beginning section of Table list. Then skip this line
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line) && (line != "Tables: table #, max seats");   )  ;

        // Now read all TableAndSeats. The reading ends, when an empty line is found. Then the fail bit is set
        for (TableAndSeats tas{}; is >> tas; t.tables.push_back(tas));

        // If we have reached the empty line, then no conversion can take place and the failbit will be set
        // This is what we expect and what we use as an loop end indicator. Reset the flag, so that we can continue to read
        if (is.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit) is.clear();

        return is;
    }
    // Simple output with inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Tables& t) {
        for (const TableAndSeats& tas : t.tables) os << tas;
        return os << '\n';
    }
};


// Complete Menu consisting of menu entries
struct Menu {

    std::vector<MenuEntry> menuEntries{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Menu& m) {

        // Search beginning section of Table list. Then skip this line
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line) && (line != "Menu: listing of the full menu: item code, name, price"); );

        // Read all table entries
        for (MenuEntry me{}; is >> me; m.menuEntries.push_back(me));

        return is;
    }
    // Simple output with inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Menu& m) {
        for (const MenuEntry& me : m.menuEntries) os << me;
        return os << '\n';
    }
};

struct MenuAndTables {

    Tables tables;
    Menu menu;

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, MenuAndTables& mat) {
        return is >> mat.tables >> mat.menu;
    }
    // Simple output with inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MenuAndTables& mat) {
        return os << "\nTables\n\n" << mat.tables << "\nMenu\n\n" << mat.menu << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\text.txt" }; sourceFileStream) {


        MenuAndTables menuAndTables;

        // Read complete file and store result in our variable
        sourceFileStream >> menuAndTables;

        // Output everything to console
        std::cout << menuAndTables;

    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Cannot open source file\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hm, a lot of code. But all parts are very similar. The key in reading from an IOStream is to use the native iostream functions. Basically there are 2 "functions" that we will use.

The extractor operator `>>` that is used to extract information from a stream, so, to read data. Like for example in `is >> tableNumber >> maxSeats;` This you know already.

The other one is the inserter operator `<<`. This will insert data in the output stream, so, it will write data. Like in `os << tableNumber << maxSeats;`. And this you know as well.

Maybe, you did not yet know, that you can overwrite both operators for your own Data-Types. So, If you have a very simple `struct` (a data type) like in

```
struct TableAndSeats {
    unsigned int tableNumber{};
    unsigned int maxSeats{};
};
```

then you can define an extractor and inserter operator for your new data type.

The signature of such functions is always the same:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, YourNewType& ynt)            // Extractor
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const YourNewType& ynt)      // Inserter
```

In those, you can define the specific read and write operations, needed for your new type. And you return a reference to the given `stream`, so that the operations can be chained.

And now, we solve the first very small problem. We want to read the table number ant the number of max seats for this table. In your example above, we want to read `1 2` from one line in the text file. This first small problem we solve by defining a small struct and overwrite the inserter operator:

```
// One Table and the maximum number of seats for it
struct TableAndSeats {
    unsigned int tableNumber{};
    unsigned int maxSeats{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator for this type for easier reading of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TableAndSeats& tas) {
        return is >> tas.tableNumber >> tas.maxSeats;
    }
};
```

We have a struct containing 2 variables for "tableNumber" and "maxSeats". And an ultra simple extractor, that extract this info from stream "is": `return is >> tas.tableNumber >> tas.maxSeats;`. That's it. It will read "1" and "2" into our variables. Not more and not less.

Now, next level of complexity. We want to read all "tableNumber" and "maxSeat". And we want to skip the not needed line.

OK, then we define a new struct, a new Type, containing many tables. These we will store in a `std::vector`. Additionally, we want to start this activity, after we have read the header line. The header line will be ignored and not stored.

```
for (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line) && (line != "Tables: table #, max seats");   )
```

Uh Oh, what a strange for loop?

No, a normal for loop. Just as in `for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)`. In the declaration part ("int i=0;") we put the definition of the "line" vaiable and initialize it with "empty".

In the condition part, we use, `std::getline` which will read a complete line and return indirectly a boolean value, depending on if that worked or not:

Additionally, we check, if the line contains the header text for this section.

The iteration part of the for loop will be empty. It is not needed, beause `std::getline` advances the "pointer" into the stream.

With all that we will read line be line, until we have read the header line. This we will ignore. We will not store the contents of variable line anywhere.

Then, next, we want to read all the table data.

For that, we use a similar for loop. In the initialization section we simply define a variable of type "TableAndSeats".

Then we use the extractor operator that we defined above and read all "TableAndSeats", until `is >> tas` returns false. Otherwise, we store the data in the vector.

But why would the extractor operation return false? For that you need to know, that the extraction operation returns a reference to the originally given stream (please see in the definition above). And, the streams bool operator is overwritten. It will return false, if there is a problem.

And a problem will occure because if we trty to read something from an empty line, this will not work. So, for `is >> tas.tableNumber >> tas.maxSeats` there cannot be an assignment to the variables, because the line is empty. As a result, the streams failbit will be set. The bool operator of the stream will return false and the for loop will be terminated.

In oder to prevent blocking of further file io operations, we clear the failbit. Then, we can continue to extract data.

We use the complete similar approch for "MenuEntries" and "Menu". Everything with the similar approach.

And last but not least, we put the "tables" and "menu" in one class and define again an extractor operator for that. This is totally simple, because it will simply use the alread defined extractors from the embedded classes. So,

```
return is >> mat.tables >> mat.menu;
```

will read all tables (which will read all table entries) and the menu with all menu entries.

We solved the big prblem, by previously solving small problems.

In main, we will just define the above compound class and use the extractor operator to read the complete file into the variable.

For the output, we overwrite the inserter operator of all classes and use the same simple mechanisms.

Please study. If you have questions, I am happy to answer.